# In JavaScript (specifically node.js) how can I generate a reusable list of dynamically generated and incremented variable names using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating a custom Gutenberg block using node.js and REACT. Eventually this will be a Bootstrap slider that can have slides added dynamically. For each slide the user needs to upload a video or image. I am doing this using the built-in component that is part of @wordpress/block-editor.

I've added 3  `<MediaUpload>`  components in the `<InspectorControls>` that will display in the right block controls column in WordPress.

They work by calling an "onChange" function that updates the backgroundImage attribute that is originally set in block.json.

```
<InspectorControls>
    <PanelRow>
        <fieldset class="media-upload">
        <strong>Select slide 1 video or image:</strong>
            <MediaUpload
                onSelect={onImageSelect}
                type={ [ 'image', 'video' ] }
                value={backgroundImage} 
                render={({ open }) => (
                    <button onClick={open}>
                        Upload Image!
                    </button>
                )}
            />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="media-upload">
        <strong>Select slide 2 video or image:</strong>
            <MediaUpload
                onSelect={onImageSelect}
                type={ [ 'image', 'video' ] }
                value={backgroundImage}
                render={({ open }) => (
                    <button onClick={open}>
                        Upload Image!
                    </button>
                )}
            />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="media-upload">
        <strong>Select slide 3 video or image:</strong>
            <MediaUpload
                onSelect={onImageSelect}
                type={ [ 'image', 'video' ] }
                value={backgroundImage}
                render={({ open }) => (
                    <button onClick={open}>
                        Upload Image!
                    </button>
                )}
            />
        </fieldset>
    </PanelRow>
</InspectorControls>
```

**EDIT**. I'm updating this question now that Teemu has clarified that variable names in JavaScript can't be dynamic.

To simplify the question. How can I write the below 3 functions in less lines of code? I think I need to increment the attribute backgroundImage[1] using a loop, but I can't figure out how to write this?

```
const onImageSelect1 = ( imageObject ) => {
        setAttributes( { backgroundImage1: imageObject.url } )
}

const onImageSelect2 = ( imageObject ) => {
        setAttributes( { backgroundImage2: imageObject.url } )
}

const onImageSelect3 = ( imageObject ) => {
        setAttributes( { backgroundImage3: imageObject.url } )
}
```

Comment: JavaScript has no concept for dynamic variable names. Use an appropriate data strucure instead, like object, array, map or set.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu for clarifying that in JavaScript we can't set dynamic variables. I've updated the question now with an edit to simplify things.